# Show compiler info in Bazel

Tags: c++, bazel, toolchain, issue-tracking

I am trying to report a bug for a project using Bazel. As part of the issue report I would like to include information about the used C++ compiler.

Which command can I use to do so?

`bazel build -s //the_target` shows me that `external/local_config_cc/wrapped_clang` seems to be the compiler. In `bazel-<project>/...` I can find that path, but running the executable `wrapped_clang` in there, just leads to an abort.

Answer (score 3):

This answer only applies if you're using Bazel autoconfigured C++ toolchain. If you don't you'll have to modify it.

So for debugging the best would be to zip entire `local_config_cc` and also to provide version of the compiler (`$CC --version`). You get the `local_config_cc` at:

```
`bazel info output_base`/external/local_config_cc
```

Path to the compiler is written into the `wrapped_clang` script in case of the toolchain that supports both C++ and ObjC (this one gets enabled when Xcode is properly detected). C++ only toolchain invokes compiler directly (but the CROSSTOOL file can still be useful for debugging). And just in case, you can force C++ only toolchain by setting `BAZEL_USE_CPP_ONLY_TOOLCHAIN=1` environment variable.